# calculate set clock uncertainty from ppm (ALTERA FPGA)

Tags: fpga

So I have a 125mhz with ppm of 300, my calculations are:

300 ppm is 0.03% of 8 ns -> 2.4ps ~3ps

So I had put on the SDC file:

```
set_clock_uncertainty -rise_from [get_clocks {clk125}] -rise_to [get_clocks {clk125}] -setup 0.003
set_clock_uncertainty -rise_from [get_clocks {clk125}] -fall_to [get_clocks {clk125}] -setup 0.003 
set_clock_uncertainty -fall_from [get_clocks {clk125}] -rise_to [get_clocks {clk125}] -setup 0.003 
set_clock_uncertainty -fall_from [get_clocks {clk125}] -fall_to [get_clocks {clk125}] -setup 0.003 

set_clock_uncertainty -rise_from [get_clocks {clk125}] -rise_to [get_clocks {clk125}] -hold 0.003
set_clock_uncertainty -rise_from [get_clocks {clk125}] -fall_to [get_clocks {clk125}] -hold 0.003 
set_clock_uncertainty -fall_from [get_clocks {clk125}] -rise_to [get_clocks {clk125}] -hold 0.003 
set_clock_uncertainty -fall_from [get_clocks {clk125}] -fall_to [get_clocks {clk125}] -hold 0.003
```

Is that looks right?
Or I should double the value?

Any advice welcome.